# How to Recursive call in F#

Tags: c#, f#

I am converting a c# recursive function to f#. I am not really familiar with F#. I had a bunch of errors with I dont know why. I did look up the [recursive function syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/recursive-functions-the-rec-keyword) but with all the if statements I have, I am confused on how to write it in f#.

Here are the c# recursive function

```
    private List<double> ReturnClosestInList(List<double> allKey, int begin, int end)
    {
        if (end >= begin)
        {
            int mid = begin + (end - begin) / 2;
            if (allKey[mid] > input) return ReturnClosestInList(allKey, begin, mid - 1);
            return ReturnClosestInList(allKey, mid + 1, end);
        }
        if (end < 0) end = begin + 1;
        if (begin < 0) begin = end + 1;
        if (end > allKey.Count - 1) end = begin - 1;
        if (begin > allKey.Count - 1) begin = end - 1;
        return new List<double> { allKey[begin], allKey[end] };
    }
```

And here are the f# code that I wrote and [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XZPt.png):

```
let rec ReturnClosestInList (allKey : List<double>) (start : int) (finish : int) (input : double)= 
    if(finish >= start) then
        let mid = start + (finish - start) / 2
        if(allKey.[mid] > input) then
            ReturnClosestInList allKey start (mid - 1) input
        else ReturnClosestInList allKey (start + 1) mid input

    else
        if finish < 0 then 
            finish = start + 1
        elif start < 0 then
            start = finish + 1
        elif finish > allKey.Length - 1 then
            finish = start - 1
        else start > allKey.Length - 1 then
            start = finish - 1

    let c : List<double> = [allKey.[start]; allKey.[finish]]
    c
```

Comment: You are trying to assign a new value to immutable values. In F# `=` is an equality operator, not an assignment operator. If the value was mutable, then you would use the assignment operator `<-`.

Comment: Instead of trying to modify the immutable parameters, consider creating new local variables instead.

Comment: When you need help with some errors you're getting, it is generally a good idea to provide the full text of those errors, so that whoever answers your question doesn't have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. The first is that you are treating `start` and `finish` as mutable values. The other is that your `else` branch does not return a value.

To fix the former, I think the best way is to reassign the variable using something like this:

```
let start, finish = 
    if finish < 0 then 
        start, start + 1
    elif start < 0 then
        finish + 1, finish
    elif finish > allKey.Length - 1 then
        start, start - 1
    elif start > allKey.Length - 1 then
        finish - 1, finish
    else start, finish
```

The idea is that you are defining *new* variables of the same name and you assign them both a new value. As you need to update values of one or the other, the code reassigns both of them (with the `else` branch not doing anything special).

The first issue is that both branches of your `if` have to return a result. To do this, you need to write something like this:

```
if(finish >= start) then
    let mid = start + (finish - start) / 2
    if(allKey.[mid] > input) then
        ReturnClosestInList allKey start (mid - 1) input
    else ReturnClosestInList allKey (start + 1) mid input
else
    let start, finish = 
        // (all the code to tweak start/finish goes here)
    [allKey.[start]; allKey.[finish]]
```

This way, the return value of the `if` case is whatever you get from the recursive call. The return of the other case is whatever you build using `[ ... ]`.

It is also worth noting that your code does not look very functional, so if you are learning F#, I'd recommend writing this using pattern matching rather than by converting code from C#. You'll get a much nicer and easier to understand solution.